# Silo structure advice for Wordpress/Woocommerce

Tags: seo, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a woocommerce project with cars, so at woo shop page I will be selling cars. On the other hand I would like to create a parent page with all child car brands. If you click on the child page title it will lead you to car brand details page. ( Static pages about brand info ). Also I will create link from child page to Woo category page of specific car brand.

I will have more than 300 child pages. How should I go about it? Should I make a Post type with categories ( One brand/category ) or should I create Parent page type with all subpages?

How would you go about it, and what would be the best Silo approach SEO wise?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was building such structure for a car market, which works still like a charm - the structure is like that:

cars

```
audi
    audi a3
        audi a3 black
        audi a3 coupe
        audi a3 V6
        audi a3 2.0 TFSI
        ...
        audi a3 - main configurations, `main` means `with the highest search volume`
    audi a6
        audi a6 3.0 TFSI
        audi a6 Avant
        audi a6 V8
bmw
    bmw 3
        bmw 3 315
        bmw 3 325
        bmw 3 cabrio
    bmw 5
        bmw 5 520
        bmw 5 525
```

URLs were:

- cars/audi/audi-a3/v8/
- cars/bmw/bmw-3/bmw-316/

Search for most wanted configurations (with highest search volume in your region) and build your structure along them.